# Launching activities depending how aplication was started

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am working on an application which could replace the Lock Screen.
What I want to achieve is to run different activities depending on if I just want to unlock the screen (then I want to run the activity responsible for that) or if I am running the application from the home (application directory) where I would like to show the Settings activity.

Now it is almost OK, because LockScreenActivity is being run always when the screen is locked, but I have two Icons (for both acitivies) in application directory.
I want only one, for the Settings activity

```
<activity
        android:name="com.lockscreen.LockScreenAppActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<activity
        android:name="com.lockscreen.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Any ideas? Any help?

Comment: remove the intent filter from LockScreenAppActivity

Comment: @leandrocastelli when I am removing intent filter from LockScreenAppActivity the activity is not being run when trying unlock the screen.
So it won't help unfortunately :(

Comment: So, remove just the android.intent.category.LAUNCHER . As you an see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) this category says that this entry point should be listed in the application launcher.